# Where and how to store service credentials on pure front-end application

Tags: javascript, frontend

I wish to build a pure front-end app with JavaScript running on client-side, i.e. browser. My app is supposed to make requests to 3rd part services, which require some sort of authentication method.

Backend frameworks provide config files for this sort of thing, but since JS code is all interpreted on the client machine, the config files cannot be part of the bundle.

Is there any way of securely storing the service API keys, credentials and such within the client or do I need a backend solution for this also?

Search for most popular frameworks (Angular and React) for config files resulted only in storing environment-specific URLs. I'm starting to think that I've hit a dead-end and this simply can't be done.

Comment: Of course it can't. You don't want the front end making requests to third parties as you, so either get the user to log in their own account or proxy that access via your own backend.

Comment: Even if it were possible, you should NEVER store security sensitive data (such as credentials) on client site, because it cannot be protected.

Comment: @jon So, basically building own backend for abstraction / delegation of the requests is the way to go, unless the 3rd party service in question is someting where the user can login, for example Twitter. Pretty much what I though. Thanks for the clarification. And if you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ferya Exactly! Thats why I asked it. Maybe didn't make it clear in the question, though. I'll add that.

Comment: Then the answer is no. There is no way to securely store the credentials in client side. Client side storage options are : cookies (which are text files and easily accessible) or local storage (again, easily accessible). You can encrypt the credentials, but any technical user can do reverse calculation (specially that your JS code is accessible to the end user too). So, don't waste your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends... You don't want the user to be able to sniff out any secrets you have to send to the third party, but in the case of an Implicit Grant with OAuth2, you can actually initiate and complete it in the browser.

You'll redirect to the 3rd party for login/authentication, then the user will be sent back to you with an access token good for a period of time.

That token is actually sent in a URL fragment, per the spec, so it's being sent to the browser and NOT your server. If you want to get the access token to a server, you'd need front-end code to parse the URL fragment and send its contents.

If the API will allow you to connect from the browser, you could keep everything in the browser and not need a backend server to handle credentials. But not every API will allow purely front-end authentication and API calls.

So, it depends...

Comment: Based on this answer and comments made to the question by Feryal and jon, I can decide what and how to do it. And especially what not to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you store service api creds in the client cache, or in cookies etc? Yes.  Will it be ***secure*** to send them over the wire and store in the browser? **No**.

If keeping credentials secure is part of the requirements, I would do the work to authenticate on the backend or use a third party service that does this for you.